# subtract one entry from another one in a column (in bash)

Tags: bash

I have file1 that looks like:

```
50
120
```

I want to subtract these and store the result in a variable x. So the value of $x should be 70.

I am using bash. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you give more info about file1? Does that pattern repeat, like do you want to subtract even odd numbered lines from even every time for lots of lines or do the files just have 2 lines?

Comment: It's simple. file1 has only two values in a column and I want to subtract the 1st from the 2nd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk like this:

```
x=$(awk 'NR>1{print $1-p} {p=$1}' file)
echo $x
70
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ read -d '' a b <file1; echo $((b-a))
70
```

If you need floating point arithmetic:

```
$ read -d '' a b <file1; echo "$b - $a" | bc -l
70
```

Comment: It gives me this error:
"syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator"

(I wrote the numbers in file1 for simplicity, my actual ones are decimals, if this matters)

Comment: Indeed it does, bash on its own can only compute integer expressions. You could fix by replacing `echo $((b-a))` with `echo "$b - $a" |bc`

Comment: @AndrasDeak OK.  Updated with `bc`.

Comment: @Arabisch  _"my actual ones are decimals"_ Yes, indeed, it makes a big difference.  See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

For simple files with two values, use this `awk` command:

```
awk 'NR==1{a=$1}NR==2{b=$1}END{print b-a}' file1
```